# Pyparsing finds first occurence in file

Tags: python, pyparsing

I'm parsing file via

```
output=wilcard.parseFile(myfile)
print output
```

And I do get only first match of string.

I have a big config file to parse, with "entries" which are surrounded by braces.
I expect to see all the matches that are in file or exception for not matching.

How do I achieve that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

By default, pyparsing will find the longest match, starting at the first character.  So, if your parse is given by `num = Word('0123456789')`, parsing either `"462"` or `"462-780"` will both return the same value.  However, if the `parseAll=True` option is passed, the parse will attempt to parse the entire string.  In this case, `"462"` would be matched, but parsing `"462-780"` would raise a ParseException, because the parser doens't know how to deal with the dash.

I would recommend constructing something that will match the entirety of the file, then using the `parseAll=True` flag in `parseFile()`.  If I understand your description of each entry being separated by braces correctly, one could do the following.

```
entire_file = OneOrMore('[' + wildcard + ']')
output = wildcard.parseFile(myfile,parseAll=True)
print output
```

Comment: You could also try using `wildcard.scanString` or `wildcard.searchString` after reading the entire file into a string, but then this would silently miss items that were not properly formed (and which you would presumably want to throw an exception for). To get your "many entries enclosed in braces", then the `OneOrMore('[' + entry + ']')` solution shown in this answer is the way to go.